# Securing HTML Form Submission Issues

Tags: php, html, nonce

When checking my nonce, the hidden input values ($form_action, $timestamp, and $form_hash) are returning as blank instead of returning as equal the nonce variables ($action, $time, and $hash). This is preventing my if statement from running and my form data from submitting to the database. If I directly set the respective variables as equal the code runs great and the data is inserted into the database so I am pretty sure the problem is coming from the PHP code that is inserted as the value for the hidden inputs. Does anyone know why this is returning as blank?

[image: Picture]

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Tournament Registration</h1>
            <hr style=
            "background-color:black;
            margin:auto;">
            <form
                action="/Forms/connection.php"
                method="post">
                <input
                    type = "hidden"
                    name = "timestamp"
                    value ="<?php echo $time; ?>">
                <input
                    type = "hidden"
                    name = "form_action"
                    value = "<?php echo $action; ?>">
                <input
                    type = "hidden"
                    name = "form_hash"
                    value = "<?php echo $hash; ?>">
            <div
                class="form-field">
                 <input
                    style=
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;
                    margin-top: 20px;"
                    type="text"
                    class="text"
                    name="firstname"
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div
                class="form-field">
                <input
                    style=
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;"
                    type="text"
                    class="text"
                    name="lastname"
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                    required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div
                class="form-field">
                <input
                    style=
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;"
                    type="email"
                    class="text"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div
                class="form-field">
                <input
                    style=
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;"
                    type="text"
                    class="text"
                    name="phonenumber"
                    placeholder="Phone Number"
                    required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div
                class="form-field">
                <input
                  style=
                  "width:250px;
                  padding:10px;"
                  type="text"
                  class="text"
                  name="handicap"
                  placeholder="Handicap"
                  required>
                  <br>
                  <br>
            </div>
            <div
                class="form-field">
                <select
                  style=
                  "width:250px;
                  padding:10px;"
                  class="text"
                  name="shirtsize"
                  size = 1
                  required>
                    <option
                        value=""
                        selected>
                        Shirt Size
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="S">
                        S
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="M">
                        M
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="L">
                        L
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="XL">
                        XL
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="2XL">
                        2XL
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="3XL">
                        3XL
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div
                class="form-field">
                <input
                    style=
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;
                    margin-left:auto;"
                    type="submit"
                    value="Register">
            </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

//Nonce
$time = time();
$action = 'tournament_registration';
$str = sprintf('%s_%s_%s', $action, $time, $NONCE_SALT);
$hash = hash('sha512', $str);



    if (! empty($_POST)){
        // Extract Post Data
        extract($_POST);
        
        $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
        $form_action = $_POST['form_action'];
        $form_hash = $_POST['form_hash'];
        
        echo "timestamp = "; print_r($timestamp);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "form_action = "; print_r($form_action);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "form_hash = "; print_r($form_hash);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "firstname = "; print_r($firstname);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "lastname = "; print_r($lastname);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "email = "; print_r($email);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "phonenumber = "; print_r($phonenumber);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "handicap = "; print_r($handicap);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "shirtsize = "; print_r($shirtsize);
        echo '<br/>';
        
        
        // Check Nonce
        $calc_str = sprintf('%s_%s_%s', $form_action, $timestamp, $NONCE_SALT);
        $calc_hash = hash('sha512', $calc_str);
 

        if($calc_hash == $form_hash){
            $filter_firstname = filter_var($firstname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $filter_lastname = filter_var($lastname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $filter_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
            $filter_phonenumber = filter_var($phonenumber, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $filter_handicap = filter_var($handicap, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $filter_shirtsize = filter_var($shirtsize, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
        
        if ($filter_email != false){
            //Send to database
            $mysql = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
            $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO Registration (firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, handicap, shirtsize) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $filter_firstname, $filter_lastname, $filter_email, $filter_phonenumber, $filter_handicap, $filter_shirtsize);
            $insert = $stmt->execute();
        
            //Close Connection
            $stmt->close();
            $mysql->close();
        } 
        else {
            $insert = false;
        }
    } 
    else {
        $insert = false;
    }
?>
```

Comment: the code that you have posted here doesn't define $form_action, $timestamp, and or $form_hash before you attempt to use their values. You have to assign them values first.

Comment: Hey @S. Imp, thanks for the response. Is it acceptable to define the values using the names designation in HTML? I was able to use the other input names in my form without specifically defining them in my PHP code. I have updated the PHP code with the comments you made, defining $form_action, $timestamp, and $form_hash, but I am still getting a blank value on my submission. I added a picture as well for reference.

Comment: When inspecting the HTML rendered in the browser for the form, do the hidden fields have values?

Comment: On a completely side note please [don't use placeholders as labels](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/), inline styles and use margins or padding instead of `<br>` for vertical spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The value in the inspect window shows "<?php echo $time; ?>" == $0. Same for the other 2 hidden fields.

Comment: If that is what is showing as your form values then it looks like you have an issue with your form page. Is it saved as a `.html` or `.php` file?

Comment: How to send `$time, $action and $hash` variables to the client view?

Comment: Honestly I am not 100% sure where to find the values when inspecting the form. I clicked on the hidden input code in the inspect window element tab and that is what was shown. I created the form using the html widget in Elementor. I couldn't find a file in the file manager for my website, so I am not sure where the html is saved or what it saves as.

Comment: Hey @Adam P. I apologize I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @0r3d1gger25 it's sort of hard to tell from your post, which could be clearer, but it looks like you have two distinct file: one to define your html form and then `Forms/connection.php` which contains that other PHP code. You'll note that in your code labeled 'HTML Code' you refer to variables $time, $action, and $hash but you haven't bothered to assign those any values before you try to echo them into your form. I think you need to slow down and focus on the fundamentals. In particular, don't try to echo any variable before you have assigned it a value.

Comment: @S. Imp so I need to define these in the html code as well? My understanding is that the PHP code in the hidden input values is sent to the "PHP Code" file and the $timestamp, $form_action, and $form_hash variables are set equal to the $time, $action, and $hash variables, which were assigned values in the PHP code. This is done to check the nonce and confirm the form was submitted on my page. is that not correct? I need the hidden values ($timestamp, $form_action, and $form_hash) to be equal to the ($time, $action, and $hash) variables that I defined in my PHP code when the form is submitted.